# Is My Understanding Correct

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I know there's already some similar questions on this site, but I wanted to phrase my question in a slightly different way. My question is

> What does "$F^n$ is a vector space over $F$" mean?

I think the "over $F$" is stating what type of scalar multiplication and addition can occur in $F^n$.

**For example**, if we were in the complex vector space $\mathbb{C}$, one could multiply a vector by a complex scalar or a real scalar and still obtain a complex vector, and the same thing for addition. But if we were in the real vector space, scalar multiplication and addition would be restricted to real numbers. If I tried to multiply a real vector by a complex scalar I would get a complex number. This is a problem since scalars are just supposed to stretch, shrink, change direction of a vector whereas multiplying a real vector by a complex scalar turns that vector complex. This is why when stating a vector space, we say which field it is over. However, this is often trivial because we will know what field it is over by what type of vector space it is.

Is this correct? Is this why we use this phraseology - "over $F$"?

Comment: Yes, it indicates the field of scalars.

Answer (score 1):

One **defines** a vector space over a field $F$ as a set along with two operations: vector addition and scalar multiplication from $F$.

So to say $F^n$ is a vector space of $F$ simply means that we consider the set of vectors from $F^n$ with scalar multiplication from the field $F$ (of course, multilication by scalars from this field will leave you within the set $F^n$). It isn't anything more than this definition.